# NFTs to Pixels in Map

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, nft, decentralized-applications

Development is a full - stack NFT marketplace. The contract .sol scope is primarily to allow users the ability to purchase clusters of pixels each representing an NFT - image for reference. Question lies in how to connect the NFT contracts and the frontend of the image as a world map.

Identical project
https://pixel.inc/
https://github.com/boringcrypto/pixel

Summary of what I am attempting to achieve:
The exact same thing, only  that the map is in this shape
[image]

Considerations

1. Create a React frontend that looks like the map image and connect the NFTs from the .sol - but how would this work?
2. Build the UI from the smart contract itself.

Cant find a satisfactory answer yet, I will appreciate any help. Thanks!